# How to import AD-Users in powershell and save the credentials in a logfile?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have to create a powershell-script to import AD-Users. I already have this;

```
 if(Test-path $csvPath){

      $UsersImp = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $csvPath  

      foreach ($User in $UsersImp)            
      {            
        $Displayname = $User.Vorname + " " + $User.Nachname            
        $UserFirstname = $User.Vorname           
        $UserLastname = $User.Nachname            
        $OU = "OU=Messe,DC=megagiga,DC=local"            
        $SAM = $User.Benutzeranmeldename            
        $UPN = $User.Vorname + "." + $User.Nachname + "@" + $User.Email                        
        $Password = $User.Password     

        New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName $UserFirstname -Surname $UserLastname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -CannotChangePassword $true -Enabled $true -Path $OU -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false –PasswordNeverExpires $true -AccountExpirationDate $ExpirationDate -KerberosEncryptionType -- AES256  

        Echo "Benutzer $Displayname wurde erstellt als $SAM"      
       }
 }            
 else{
      Write-Host "Der Pfad war nicht korrekt, versuchen es nochmals."
      Import
 }
```

It works, but it seems to import the users twice, because I always get an error that the users already exists. Does somebody know what's wrong?

Also I'd like to know, how I can save the credentials for each user in a logfile.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a snippet of your code and not the full code? Because you are using $ExpirationDate but you haven't set it to a value.

New-ADUser  has a parameter -WhatIf
You could use that and see what it does, or better said, would do.

If i were in your position, i would create a CSV file with 1 or 2 lines from which i know the content of. Then you know what to expect and debugging becomes more visible.

Based off your code, i don't see a reason as to why it would create each user twice.

Comment: Yep, the $ExpirationDate is already defined at the beginning. I'll try the -WhatIf. Thy :)